# Will file really disappear from SSD?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, ssd

I have a Samsung Evo 840 1TB SSD for two years. Recently I found some files I created last year just disappeared. I found a backup in my email but they could not be found anywhere on my computer.

Today I am even surprised to find an entire project folder cannot be found on my SSD. This is an important project so there is no reason that I would delete it myself.

I searched online and it seems some people also reported weird missing files on SSD. Will files really just vanish on a SSD, or it might be caused by something else? I am using windows 10. Thank you!

Comment: If files routinely disappeared from SSDs due to the SSD, itself, nobody would trust them and they would have no practical use.  It's something else.

Answer (score 3):

Files do not vanish mysteriously.  The SSD does not know what a file or folder is, nor where on the disk it is.  Unless there was a physical error with the disk, or file system corruption, files do not disappear.  And if there was, it would not likely be "one project", but a multitude of files.  If an entire "project" disappeared, more than likely you deleted or moved it.  There is no other alternative.

Comment: Actually there is - its entirely likely there is a corruption of the equivalent of the File Allocation Table (ie file index).  It could also be malware (although this is unlikely), or a firmware bug with the SSD possibly related to TRIM or other cleanup/garbage collection - which could affect the file allocation table...